# CNN kernel location for input image

Tags: neural-network, cnn, image-classification, convolutional-neural-network

Given a CNN, say AlexNet: 
[image: AlexNet]

How could one relate kernel locations at the 3rd conv block, i.e 13x13 filter size to the input image. Would that give a meaningful representation in terms of the input image.

I was thinking of just upsampling the location, from 13x13 to 224x224.

Comment: do you mean this: https://medium.com/mlreview/a-guide-to-receptive-field-arithmetic-for-convolutional-neural-networks-e0f514068807

Comment: They are not positions in the real size image. They are positions in the outputs of the previous layer.